# Matrix shortest path with jumping points

Tags: c#, .net

I have a random Matrix eg.:

```
3  A  6  8
9  2  7* 1
6  6  9  1
2  #3 4  B
```

I need to find, the shortest path from `A` to `B`. The `*` and `#` marks are jumping points. If you stay on the `*` marked number, you can jump to the `#` marked number.

I thought a lot around this, but can't solve.
How can i achive this?

Comment: _"thought a lot around this"_ would you mind sharing your thoughts with us?

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: you can use the Dijkstra Algorithme to calculate the shortest path , and modify it to take in account your jumping points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the values in your matrix are the movement cost of one field to another, the algorithm you need is [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). Wikipedia offers you some pseudo code to get started, but if you ask Google, you will find loads and loads of example implementation in every language there is.

In case the movement cost if always the same, it is a A* algorithm too, but in that special case it is [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

A* is basically Dijkstra's algorithm with the addition of considering changing movement costs.